# AVAudioPlayer time display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have a simple mp3 playing through AVAudioPlayer and I want to be able to display how much time is left.

I know the answer includes subtracting `AVAudioPlayer.duration` from `AVAudioPlayer.currentTime` but I don't know how to implement a function which calculates it while it's playing (like an onEnterFrame in Actionscript I guess). At present `currentTime` is static, i.e. zero.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would go for an NSTimer. Schedule it to run every second while the media is played and so you can keep your UI updated with the time left.

```
// Place this where you start to play
NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(updateTimeLeft)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
```

And create the method to update you UI:

```
- (void)updateTimeLeft {
    NSTimeInterval timeLeft = self.player.duration - self.player.currentTime;

    // update your UI with timeLeft
    self.timeLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f seconds left", timeLeft];
}
```

Comment: Thank you vfn, it looks like the perfect solution only one problem I've found: The timer is not firing!

Comment: Ah yep just needed to use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` instead of `timerWithTimeInterval`

Comment: Yeah, you would need to fire it or to use the scheduled method. It's edited now!

Answer (score 1):

I use it in swift and it work:

```
// this for show remain time
let duration = Int((player1?.duration - (player1?.currentTime))!)
let minutes2 = duration/60
let seconds2 = duration - minutes2 * 60
durLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes2,seconds2) as String

//this for current time
let currentTime1 = Int((player1?.currentTime)!)
let minutes = currentTime1/60
let seconds = currentTime1 - minutes * 60
curLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
```