# Is there an alternative to using an NSTimer to display remaining time of audio file with AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, avaudioplayer

I play music with `AVAudioPlayer` and want to display the remaining time. It seems many [suggest an NSTimer that fires every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571494/avaudioplayer-time-display) but I am afraid this is inefficient and prone to error. Since `NSTimer` is not very precise timing (I have heard) it can be that the timer fires twice within the same second of audio, and the countdown then jumps over one second. Also this is a pull model.

Is there a more savvy way where `AVAudioPlayer` would call my countdown every time a second ticks away?

Comment: NSTimeInterval remaining = audioPlayer.duration - audioPlayer.currentTime;
This will give you the remaining time I think, but calling a method every second will be done best using a timer. There is no way the AVAudioPlayer can help you with that.

Comment: A repeating timer on a 1 second interval will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While NSTimer is semi-inaccurate, you can still just have it call every second or so and get information from the `currentTime` property of the song, and compare it to the `duration` property. From that you can calculate remaining time etc.

[AVAudioPlayer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are no callbacks available to help you handle updating the time display when playing an audio file. The NSTimer method is how it should be done. If you're concerned with inaccuracies in the display due to NSTimer firing precision, just reduce your timer's update interval. Keep the workload light in your implementation and set the interval to 500ms, or perhaps 250ms...